# Dynamic css for one cell in DataTable - PrimeNG

Tags: css, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using databale from PrineNG in my angular+typescript project.

I have datatable with some editable cells.
I want to change cell background color in some cases.
I know I can use 'bodyStyleClass'. But I need to take some css class based on whole row (I need to compare two values).
It means background color should be dynamically changed by my method.

How I can do this?

Comment: Is this what are you looking for? https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/style

Comment: I'll look for this solution. Thanks.